# Choosing the color of only one of the plotted elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot` to plot a set of values in R and want to colour them according to their sensor name. However, I'd like to change the colour of *one* of the sensors (not all of them as they are many). Do you have any suggestions?

I'm going to use the following command:

```
 ggplot(molted1, aes( Duration,value,group=test ))+
 geom_point(aes(color=sensor))+ 
 facet_grid(~test,scales = "free") + 
 theme_bw()+ 
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=3))+
 theme(legend.position = "none",axis.title=element_text(size=11))+labs(x="",y="Temperature \n(°C)")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to map the color to the `logical` test of `sensor == selected` and then supply the background and highlight colors to `scale_color_manual()`.

If you want to more than one `sensor` to get highlighted and show different colors for just those ones, you may want to take a look at the {gghighlight} package which does this nicely.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = carb == 4), size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey50", "red")) +
  facet_grid(~gear)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>